# Proving uniform boundedness of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, equicontinuity

Let $(f_{n})$ be a sequence in $C[0,1]$ that is equicontinuous on $[0,1]$, and let $p\in [0,1]$ be given. Show that if $(f_{n}(p))^{\alpha}_{n=1}$ is bounded, then $(f_{n})$ is uniformly bounded.

Can I use Arzela Ascoli theorem to prove the above problem?

Comment: You can't use the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem; rather, this exercise shows that your hypotheses imply that the hypotheses of the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem would apply.

Comment: We hae that $|f_n(p)|<M<\infty,\ $ and we also know that for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and $x,y\in [0,1],\ $ there is a $\delta >0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<1 .$ 

Cover $[0,1]$ with a finite number, say $N$ of balls of diameter $<\delta$, centered at the points $x_1<\cdots <x_N.$

Let $x\in [0,1].$ Wlog assume $x<p$ and $x\in B(x_1).$ Then,

$|f_n(x)|\le |f_n(x)-f_n(x_1)|+\dots +|f_n(x_m)-f_n(p)|+|f_n(p)|<N+M.$